# Use the handle to propagate two-by-two cell references in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel for macOS, I'm trying to use the cell bottom-right handle to apply a formula with cell reference. This usually works fine, but in this case I want to move the cell references on a two by two basis.

Example:

The cells K1-L1-M1 have the same formula but skip one cell each time, and I want to expand this pattern onto the N1 cell by using the handle:

```
K1=A1
L1=C1
M1=E1
N1=G1 => ??
```

A screenshot of the situation:

[image]

The `K` cell has `=A1` in its formula. The `L` cell has `=C1`. I'd like to make so that when I use the handle to "move" that formula along, this "going two-by-two" pattern is taken into account.

What is happening instead, is that in the manipulation shown in the image, the `N` cell will be updated with `=F1` (actual result) instead of `=G1` (which would be the expected result).

How can I make Excel apply this two-by-two pattern without having the fill in every single cell manually?

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(1:1,(COLUMN(A1)-1)*2 + 1)
```

The `*2` is the pattern and the `+1` is the column number of the first data item.